# Hibernate criteraia not retrieving the data from database

Tags: hibernate

Hi I am new bee to the Hibernate as I am Using the Criteria to retrieve the data from the database ,but I am unable to fetch the data if the record matches also. The below is the code snippet I used .The below method is mainly used to check whether the user in the list (groups) is admin or not by comparing with (QuickUrlAdmin table of adminUser column).

But I am getting the request1 size as 0 by checking in the logs (Records exists in the database) .Any suggestions

```
private boolean isAdmin() throws AppException {
try {
 Session session = PersistenceManager.getSession(); 
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(QuickUrlAdmin.class);
             List<QuickUrl> request1 = null;             
             for (String group : groups) { //groups is a list  filled from another method 
                 log.debug("group:" + group);               
                 request1 =criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("adminUser", group)).list();
                 log.debug(" Request Object :" +request1.size());                
             }
}
```

Direct HQL Query working fine

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM QuickUrlAdmin WHERE adminUser = :group_name";
             SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
             query.addEntity(QuickUrlAdmin.class);           
                for (String group : groupList) {
                     log.debug("*********group:" + group);              
                     query.setParameter("group_name", group);
                     List<QuickUrl> results1 = query.list();                
                     log.debug(" Request Object :" +results1.size());
                 }
```

Console Log

```
09:34:34,479 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:34,479 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:BES12_002 - Default
09:34:34,499 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:34,775 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:34,774 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:34,776 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:34,776 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:BES200CNC Users
09:34:34,777 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:35,053 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,052 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:35,054 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,053 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:ValueLabs Consultants - eCommerce BE
09:34:35,055 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:35,328 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,328 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:35,329 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,329 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Livelink - Consultant 2
09:34:35,331 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:35,605 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,603 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:35,606 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,606 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:BTS-Hyderabad Team
09:34:35,608 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:35,882 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,881 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:35,883 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:35,883 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Team.josims
09:34:35,885 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:36,157 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,156 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:36,157 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,157 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:BTS_VL_DEV
09:34:36,160 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:36,433 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,433 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:36,434 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,433 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Password Policy for Standard Users
09:34:36,435 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:36,713 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,713 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:36,714 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,714 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Team.jschen
09:34:36,716 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:36,989 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,989 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:36,990 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:36,990 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Team.mthota
09:34:36,992 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=?
09:34:37,264 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:37,264 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:37,265 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:37,265 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:DirectReports.mthota
09:34:37,267 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:37,542 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:37,542 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:37,543 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:37,543 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Team.bmalencia
09:34:37,545 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:37,818 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:37,817 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:37,819 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:37,819 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Team.ropayne
09:34:37,821 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:38,095 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,094 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:38,096 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,096 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Team.sstrout
09:34:38,098 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:38,369 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,369 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:38,370 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,370 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:EVPol5
09:34:38,371 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:38,646 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,646 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:38,647 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,647 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:RIM INDIA - Consultants and Contractors
09:34:38,649 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:38,925 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,925 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:38,926 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:38,926 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:BPM - RIM ALL
09:34:38,928 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:39,201 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:39,200 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:39,202 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:39,202 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:JIRA Users
09:34:39,204 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:39,480 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:39,479 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:39,481 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:39,480 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:Self Service Admin Portal
09:34:39,482 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:39,755 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:39,755 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:39,756 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:39,756 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:CodeCollaborator Users
09:34:39,758 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:40,035 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:40,034 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:40,036 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:40,036 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:335 - *********group:External - Contractors and Consultants
09:34:40,038 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADMINUSER=? and this_.ADM
09:34:40,313 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:40,312 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.isAdmin:337 -  Request Object :0
09:34:40,609 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:40,609 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.getLoginURL:62 - called
09:34:40,610 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:40,610 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.getAdminByKey:104 - called
09:34:40,612 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID10_0_, this_.KEY as KEY10_0_, this_.DATA_FIELD as DATA3_10_0_, this_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED4_10_0_, this_.MODIFIED_DATE as MODIFIED5_10_0_ from QUICKURL.ADMIN this_ where this_.KEY=?
09:34:41,454 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:41,453 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.getRegExNameValidation:76 - called
09:34:41,455 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:41,454 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.getAdminByKey:104 - called
09:34:41,457 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID10_0_, this_.KEY as KEY10_0_, this_.DATA_FIELD as DATA3_10_0_, this_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED4_10_0_, this_.MODIFIED_DATE as MODIFIED5_10_0_ from QUICKURL.ADMIN this_ where this_.KEY=?
09:34:42,267 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:42,266 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.getRegExUrlValidation:90 - called
09:34:42,268 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:42,267 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.getAdminByKey:104 - called
09:34:42,270 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID10_0_, this_.KEY as KEY10_0_, this_.DATA_FIELD as DATA3_10_0_, this_.CREATED_DATE as CREATED4_10_0_, this_.MODIFIED_DATE as MODIFIED5_10_0_ from QUICKURL.ADMIN this_ where this_.KEY=?
09:34:43,086 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:43,086 DEBUG ParseFieldAnnotation.getMetaInfo:23 - called
09:34:43,089 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:43,088 DEBUG ParseFieldAnnotation.getMetaInfo:43 - called
09:34:43,145 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select * from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_ID not in (select COLUMN_ID from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_NAME like ? and upper(DATA_TYPE)=?)
09:34:45,280 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select * from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_ID not in (select COLUMN_ID from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_NAME like ? and upper(DATA_TYPE)=?)
09:34:48,801 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select * from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_ID not in (select COLUMN_ID from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_NAME like ? and upper(DATA_TYPE)=?)
09:34:51,351 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: select * from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_ID not in (select COLUMN_ID from USER_TAB_COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME=? and COLUMN_NAME like ? and upper(DATA_TYPE)=?)
09:34:53,702 INFO  [STDOUT] 09:34:53,701 DEBUG AppServiceImpl.getPagingQuickUrls:432 - config : limit=12  offset=0  sortField=null  sortDir=NONE  quickUrlPrefix=null  rimnetUserId=null  viewUnpublishedUrls=false  redirectQuery=null
```

Comment: HI I have created a criteria on QuickUrlAdmin class like below                                             Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(QuickUrlAdmin.class);
             List<QuickUrl> request1 = null;

Comment: i am asking why there is discrepancy in classes used in my above comment.

Comment: I added the Criteria to QuickUrlAdmin  but I am type casting the result list to QuickUrl can we add two classes to one criteria ?,I tried with direct HQL query as above its working fine but I am unable to get the same result through criteria

Comment: @chaitanaya try with List<QuickUrlAdmin>, also did you see the generated query in server console or logs , have you enabled query logging using `show_sql` = true

Comment: I modified in the hibernate configuration file to show_sql=true but can you please mention me how to see the criteria query hitting the database

Comment: As per your suggestion I Checked the console log after making the show_sl=true it is displaying in this manner                    Hibernate: select this_.ID as ID12_0_, this_.ADMINUSER as ADMINUSER12_0_ from QUICKURL.QUICKURLADMIN this_ where this_.ADMINUSER=?

Comment: try with this , and show query

`private boolean isAdmin() throws AppException {
try {
 Session session = PersistenceManager.getSession(); 
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(QuickUrlAdmin.class);
                       
             for (String group : groups) { //groups is a list  filled from another method 
                 log.debug("group:" + group);               
                 log.debug(" Request Object :" +criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("adminUser", group)).list().size());                
             }
}`

Comment: I have attached the complete console can you please have a look

Comment: also instead of loop in my above comment, jsut pass some harcoded group for which data is there, and try to execute

Comment: I tried with harding coding some data which exists in the database but no luck ,I guess there is some problem in criteria unable to figur eit out

Comment: @ankur Small Question if we observer in the console output every time the query which we are printing is appending with the previous query value is this expected ?

Comment: @ankur I made a modification like added this code snippet inside the foreach  loop itself Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(QuickUrlAdmin.class); now its working fine ,  but what I am thinking is there an performance issue? is this a right way to  add this code snippet directly inside a loop

Comment: frankly speaking i did not understand the intent behind ur logic, can u elaborate little more in plain english text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understand from your question is

1.) You have some list of names, `groups`.

2.) You are fetching the `QuickUrlAdmin`, where `adminUser` is equal to passed name.

Basically, you are iterating one by one on groups and hitting database everytime.

Try this, will solve your purpose

```
SELECT * FROM QuickUrlAdmin WHERE adminUser IN :groups
```

where groups is just the `list of String`.

**Code after modification**

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM QuickUrlAdmin WHERE adminUser IN :groups";
             SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
             query.addEntity(QuickUrlAdmin.class);           
             query.setParameter("groups", groups);
             List<QuickUrl> results1 = query.list();
```

**Criteria API**

```
private boolean isAdmin() throws AppException {
try {
 Session session = PersistenceManager.getSession(); 
 Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(QuickUrlAdmin.class);
             List<QuickUrl> request1 = null;             
             request1 =criteria.add(Restrictions.in("adminUser", groups)).list();
             log.debug(" Request Object :" +request1.size());    
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ankur modified Criteria API worked with no issues and I am able to compare with database in efficient manner ,once again thanks alot for looking into it and helping me.